# Moving text using sed

Tags: xml, sed, move, reorganize

I have a xml file with following contents:

```
<query_1>false</query_1>
<query_2>true</query_2>
<query_3>true</query_3>
<query_4>false</query_4>
<query_5>false</query_5>
```

Is it possible to reorganize the file using sed, so it would pick up "true" and outputs them into one line like this:

```
<query>2,3</query>
```

Regards,
Irek

Comment: must it be done with sed?  This is almost trivial with Perl.

Comment: show us the perl then :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's not the simplest solution, but you could try this:

```
sed -n '/<query_[0-9]*>true<\/query/{:a;s/^<query_\([0-9]*\)>.*/\1/;tb;ba;:b;H};${g;s/^\n//;s/\n/,/g};$s/.*/<query>&<\/query>/p' file
```

The output using your example file is exactly what you want:

```
<query>2,3</query>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following sequences of commands returns the string you request

```
$ grep true input | sed 's/>//g' | cut -d _ -f 3 | printf "<query>%s</query>" `paste -d, - -`
<query>2,3</query>
```

Gives:

```
<query>2,3</query>
```